# AS2 Load multiple swf files having same name classes

Tags: actionscript-2

As the title of the question. I have one swf that loads other swf files using `createEmptyMovieClip`, `loadMovie` and for the destroy `removeMovieClip`, and `delete`.

Each external swf file has the same name class with the other loaded.

After loading the external swf files the view part works perfect! But the class its always the first loading ....

any suggestions?

loader.swf - file_loader.as

```
class file_loader extends MovieClip 
{
    public var tmpMC:MovieClip;

    public function file_loader() 
    {
    }

    function onLoad()
    {
        var that = this;
        this["btn_a"].onPress = function() {

            that.loadFile("file_a.swf");
        }
        this["btn_b"].onPress = function() { 

            that.loadFile("file_b.swf");
        }
    }

    function loadFile(filename:String):Void
    {
        tmpMC.removeMovieClip();
        delete tmpMC;

        tmpMC = new MovieClip();
        tmpMC = _parent.createEmptyMovieClip("tmpMC", -16384);

        tmpMC.loadMovie(filename);
    }
}
```

file_a.fla - mainClass.as

```
class mainClass extends MovieClip 
{
    public function mainClass() 
    {
    }

    function onLoad()
    {
        this["txt"].text = "file_a.swf: function onLoad()";
    }
}
```

file_b.fla - mainClass.as

```
class mainClass extends MovieClip 
{
    public function mainClass() 
    {
    }

    function onLoad()
    {
        this["txt"].text = "file_b.swf: function onLoad()";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do mean by : "But the class its always the first loading" ?

Comment: I mean: If I load the file_a.swf First works correctly and print in the monitor the text `file_a.swf: function onLoad()` after that using `removeMovieClip` load the second file file_b.swf the program still prints in the monitor `file_a.swf: function onLoad()` Because the loaded files use the `mainClass` same name class

Comment: If i change the class name of the second file from `mainClass` to `mainClassB` the whole project works perfect, but I have about 600 files to change the class names, also each file has 8 classes ... omg :)